# Markov Chain or Not?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> An urn always contains 2 balls. The ball colours are red and blue. At
> each stage, a ball is randomly chosen and then replaced by a new ball,
> which with probability 0.8 is the same colour, and with probability
> 0.2 is the opposite colour, as the ball it replaces. Now, if we define $X_n=1$ if the nth selection is red, and $X_n=0$ if the nth selection
> is blue, will $\{X_n, n\ge 1\}$ be a Markov chain?

I personally think it is a Markov Chain because it fits the definition:

> Markov Chains are processes where the distribution of the future steps depends only on the present state of the process.

The next outcome depends only on what's currently in the urn. However, the author disagrees. So is this a Markov Chain?

Comment: The probability that the next selection is red depends on the current make up of the urn, which depends on the history of choices, not just the last one.  Of course you can modify the problem to consider states labeled by the number of red balls in the urn (so, $3$ states).  That system only depends on the prior state.

Comment: @lulu The 3 states are what I had on mind. Thanks for the response.

Comment: The specific question you quote is "will $\{X_n, n\ge 1\}$ be a Markov chain?". While you're correct  that the *number of red balls in the urn* is a Markov chain, $\ X_n\ $ *is not the number of red balls in the urn*, and the answer to the *question actually quoted* is "no".